# javascript zoom default image after change image src value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

There's a problem with my javascript here. First, if i click the image it will zoom the image. The problem is when the image change to different one and click, it still zoom the first image, not the new one.

My html (container to show image and zoom it)

```
<div class="col-md-8">
     <span  id='ex3' class="zoom">
       <img class="img-responsive" id="myImage" width='750' height='550' src="<?php echo "./image/product/p1/". $row['item_image']. ".jpg"; ?>">
     </span>
</div>
```

My html (next image i want to click and zoom)

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
   <a href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item subimage"  onclick="changeImage1(); <?php $show1="./image/product/p1/". $row['item_image']. ".jpg"; ?>" src="<?php echo "./image/product/p1/". $row['item_image']. ".jpg"; ?>" alt="">
   </a>
</div>
```

My Javascript in body tag

```
function changeImage1() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    var submage = document.getElementsByClassName('subimage')[1].src; 
    image.src= submage;        
}
```

My javascript in head tag (zoom function)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('#ex3').zoom({ on:'click' });         
 });
```

How to fix it, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It may be a caching issue with the `zoom()` plugin. Check the documentation of that plugin for any methods which refresh the content. If there aren't any you may have to destroy it and re-instantiate.

Comment: how to destroy and re-instantiate?

Comment: Again, that depends entirely on the plugin. Check with the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the id="ex3" in the next image click zoom html.
Try somethng like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('img').zoom({ on:'click' });         
    });
```

Comment: not work, after change #ex3 to img it can't zoom anymore

Comment: @Shawn how about this one? $('img').parent().zoom({ on:'click' });

Comment: Still like my current problem. nothing change. just can zoom the default image.

Comment: there's little weird, in the container it only zoom default image, the second image zoom but not in the container.

Comment: You can check the documentation whichever plugin you are using. It should say there how to use it for multiple images.